# 'Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function' is thrown when running second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a jquery function which runs perfectly the first time but when I try to run it the second time it throws this error -

```
Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
```

Here is my function

```
function myfunction(month, records) {
      $.ajax({url: "/JustLarv/public/gMap/records/" + records, success: function(result){
        Cookies.set('month', month);
        $(".map").html(result);
      }});

      $.ajax({url: "/JustLarv/public/qlty_sor", success: function(res){
        Cookies.set('month', month);
        $(".qlty_sor_chart").html(res);
        // $(".qlty_chart").html(res);
      }});
}
```

Comment: Are you loading a `slim` version of jQuery in one of the request responses? Or some other script that overwrites `$`?

Comment: @charlietfl I am using the normal jquery version and don't see anything that is overwriting $

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you comment out the first ajax, does the second one work?

Comment: @Taplar yes if I comment out the first ajax then the second one is working without any problem but when I delete the second ajax then the first one still gives me the same error

Comment: Ok, next curiosity.  If you comment out the `$('.map').html(result)` part of your first ajax call, does the second one start working?

Comment: @Taplar yes if I comment out  $('.map').html(result) then the second one is still working perfectly fine

Comment: Then that suggests the result that you are appending to the map element contains javascript which is causing the issue.  Not the script you provided in the question.  When you append markup to the page that contains script logic, jQuery will run an eval against it so that script executes.  If that script encounters an error, it can appear as if the jQuery had an issue because the error originated from an action that jQuery invoked.  However to solve the issue you will need to take a look at the script that is being appended to the page to see what it is doing and how it is causing the error.

Comment: that solved it, thanks for pointing out  @Taplar I didn't realize I was using slim jQuery in the file that was rendering the google map

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for your help, silly me I didn't check the jquery version in my map rendering file

Comment: I would question why your including a jquery file in your render when it already exists on the parent page.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i was loading jquery again in the nested view or html. I deleted that reference and worked.